# Populating Django model field from another model field value

Tags: django, performance, django-models, orm, query-optimization

I added a something like this

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.quantity)
```

and Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
inventory = models.OneToOneField(Inventory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@property
def stock(self):
    if self.inventory:
        return self.inventory.quantity
    else:
        return 0
```

So now for stock to be populated it will check the inventory model

But I have concerns regarding the performance of this way. When i look for product.stock

[image]

Is it the right approach ?

What would happen if i get 1000s of products ?

What's the better way to do this considering performance and scalability ?

I am also open to idea for re-creating the model architecture if no other way found.

Hope you will guide me right way.. Looking forward for your reply.

Thanks & Regards

Manish